# Variable doesn't get updated when I run a loop

Tags: c, for-loop, dynamic-memory-allocation

I want to iterate through a word and print each of its characters, together with its ASCII number.

I've tried

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using std::cout;

int main()
{
    char cWord[30] = {"Larissa"};
    int iCounter = 0;
    char cLetter = cWord[iCounter];

    for (iCounter = 0; iCounter < 5; iCounter++) {
        printf("%c == %d \n", cLetter, cLetter);
    }
}
```

but that just prints `L == 76` five times. I suppose that means the `cLetter` variable doesn't update as I run the for loop, but I don't understand why.

Comment: `char cLetter = cWord[iCounter];` needs to be *inside* the loop.

Comment: Aside, you should either change the code to pure C or use the tag [tag:c++] instead of [tag:c].

Comment: You seem to be under the misconception that your initialization of `cLetter` somehow creates a permanent relationship between `cLetter`, `cWord`, and `iCounter`.  It doesn't.  This isn't a spreadsheet.  `cLetter` will only change when you explicitly assign to it, which you only do once (in the initialization).  Try assigning to it inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update `cLetter` *in* the loop, there's no magic connection to earlier code.  Might as well move `cLetter`s scope to inside the loop as well.  Try

```c
for (iCounter = 0; iCounter < 5; iCounter++) {
        char cLetter = cWord[iCounter];
        printf("%c == %d \n", cLetter, cLetter);
    }
```

Here, `iCounter` is updated each iteration, and therefore `cLetter` is too.

Answer (score 1):

You're only assigning `cLetter` once, outside of the loop, so it remains constant throughout the loop iterations.